# Items in numbered ol in bootstrap to line up horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Objective

Per specs, I am creating a view that will look like a table (to be responsive, I decided to not go with a table). I need to have the values line up horizontally. and the `<li>` number to be centered to the left (see mockup below).

[image]

### Problem

From what I understand, there seems to be a `::before` clearfix added to the `<div>` because there is a row class wrapping the values. So this is pushing the row under the button.

[image]

### Code

Demo on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/avGjXo)

I am using `bootstrap.css` from version 3.3.5

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
            <ol id="ticketNoteList">
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            omg-seriously-wtf-is-that.jpg
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            Micky Mouse
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            11/11/2011
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            5PM 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            1 gb
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end of row -->
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div> <!-- end of columns -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-block">Attach new</button>
            <button class="btn btn-block">Delete Selected</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tables can certainly be responsive. You have tabular data. Use a table. https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Comment: You can add style="margin-top: -20px" to the <div class="row">, which will help with the vertical offset.  You could also move the <li> inside the first column.  that would prevent the additional vertical spacing, but it's a little wonky.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you, I took your advice on going with a table. But will leave this question up to get feedback on the topic anyways. Also thanks for the link, i think i would use that solution on my personal projects but it would not fit the clients exact spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use pseudo elements and data attributes like this:

HTML:

```
<li data-number="3">...</li>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
}
li:before {
  content: attr(data-number);
  float: left;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjVOdM)

Comment: That works perfect and answered me in context. I appreciate your help.